# Skip nginx basic auth for Facebook

Tags: facebook, nginx

I am working on a project which uses some of the Facebook social plugins, mainly comment box plugin. By dev server is open to public but has auth_basic set up. Is it possible to disable the this for Facebook? As the moment when I display the comment box it says

> "This url is unreachable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to this by adding Facebook's IP addresses to nginx configuration file

```
 satisfy any;
allow 66.220.144.0/20;
allow 66.220.144.0/21;
allow 66.220.152.0/21;
allow 66.220.159.0/24;
allow 69.63.176.0/20;
allow 69.63.176.0/21;
allow 69.63.176.0/24;
allow 69.63.178.0/24;
allow 69.63.184.0/21;
allow 69.171.224.0/19;
allow 69.171.224.0/20;
allow 69.171.239.0/24;
allow 69.171.240.0/20;
allow 69.171.255.0/24;
allow 74.119.76.0/22;
allow 103.4.96.0/22;
allow 173.252.64.0/18;
allow 173.252.64.0/19;
allow 173.252.70.0/24;
allow 173.252.96.0/19;
allow 204.15.20.0/22;
allow 31.13.24.0/21;
allow 31.13.64.0/18;
allow 31.13.64.0/19;
allow 31.13.64.0/24;
allow 31.13.65.0/24;
allow 31.13.66.0/24;
allow 31.13.67.0/24;
allow 31.13.68.0/24;
allow 31.13.69.0/24;
allow 31.13.70.0/24;
allow 31.13.71.0/24;
allow 31.13.72.0/24;
allow 31.13.73.0/24;
allow 31.13.74.0/24;
allow 31.13.75.0/24;
allow 31.13.76.0/24;
allow 31.13.77.0/24;
allow 31.13.78.0/24;
allow 31.13.79.0/24;
allow 31.13.80.0/24;
allow 31.13.81.0/24;
allow 31.13.82.0/24;
allow 31.13.83.0/24;
allow 31.13.84.0/24;
allow 31.13.85.0/24;
allow 31.13.86.0/24;
allow 31.13.87.0/24;
allow 31.13.88.0/24;
allow 31.13.89.0/24;
allow 31.13.90.0/24;
allow 31.13.91.0/24;
allow 31.13.92.0/24;
allow 31.13.93.0/24;
allow 31.13.94.0/24;
allow 31.13.95.0/24;
allow 31.13.96.0/19;
deny all;
auth_basic            "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I guess is gfood to explain how to get the current IPs.

Facebook provides a way yo get all IP they use:

```
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route
```

The command returns all the IPv4 and IPv6 they use. Once you get the IPs, add them to your server (Nginx, Apache, etc).

Check [The Facebook Crawler](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler) page.